# Copying a source directory into a target which is a symlink to a directory

Tags: bash, directory, symlink, cp

How do I copy a source directory's contents into a target, where the target is a symlink to a directory? Right now this gives the error `cp: cannot overwrite non-directory 'symbolic-link' with directory 'source'.`

Below is an example:

```
vagrant@devbox:~/foo$ mkdir -p bin ; touch bin/something.txt
vagrant@devbox:~/foo$ mkdir -p destination/bin
vagrant@devbox:~/foo$ mkdir -p other-dir ; ln -s `pwd`/destination/bin other-dir/bin
vagrant@devbox:~/foo$ tree
.
├── bin
│   └── something.txt
├── destination
│   └── bin
└── other-dir
    └── bin -> /home/vagrant/foo/destination/bin

5 directories, 1 file
vagrant@devbox:~/foo$ cp -v -r bin other-dir
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory 'other-dir/bin' with directory 'bin'
vagrant@devbox:~/foo$ cp -v -r -t other-dir bin
cp: cannot overwrite non-directory 'other-dir/bin' with directory 'bin'
```

Comment: Not possible with GNU cp alone.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer, and it's pretty weird: you copy 'source/.' instead of 'source'. (Why does this work?)

```
vagrant@devbox:~/foo$ cp -v -r bin/. other-dir/bin
'bin/./something.txt' -> 'other-dir/bin/./something.txt'
vagrant@devbox:~/foo$ cp -v -r -t other-dir/bin bin/.
'bin/./something.txt' -> 'other-dir/bin/./something.txt'
vagrant@devbox:~/foo$ tree
.
├── bin
│   └── something.txt
├── destination
│   └── bin
│       └── something.txt
└── other-dir
    └── bin -> /home/vagrant/foo/destination/bin

5 directories, 2 files
```